# Ubuntu 12.04 Server Load Installer Components From CD

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, server, usb

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 Server (64bit) on a Dell Insprion n5520 using a USB stick. I used the Universal-USB-Installer-1.8.9.4 which has support for 12.04 server but you can also replicate the problem with LinuxLive USB Creator 2.8.11 or unetbootin 575.

The computer boots up the installation process ok.
It gets through the Ubuntu language, locale and keyboard selection.
Then starts loading additional components. At this point it gets about a quarter of the way through then throws big error message saying "There was a problem reading data from the CD-ROM."

[image: screen photo]

When I Press no

this error arise

> Installation step failed. An installation step failed. You can try to run the following item again from the menu, or skip it and choose something else.
>
> The failing step is: Load installer components from CD

What should i do ?

Comment: Its simple, You should try to make `Bootable USB` again. the software you used  to make `bootable usb` was not successfully made it bootable. This time try `Startup Disk Creator` to make USB Bootable. For this contact any person having Ubuntu installed in his/her system.

Comment: Done , it's working man .

Comment: Ok. then I'm writing this as an answer.. Just accept it.. It would help others to find their solution..!! And what worked for you? Making again bootable USB or using `Startup Disk Creator`? Mention that also..

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, You should try to make Bootable USB again. The software that you used to make `bootable usb` was not successfully made it bootable. This time try `Startup Disk Creator` to make USB Bootable.
For this contact any person having Ubuntu installed in his/her system. Or use your previous Live Ubuntu CD/DVD (if you have).